# Why is UseEffect not launching the entire async function?

Tags: reactjs, use-effect

I am using Auth0 on a react application for authentication.  After authenticating, I am trying to save the data from authentication to the database (I'm using node.js and mongoose/mongodb).  I created a function that makes a post request and also accesses a token with an Auth0 function.  When I execute the function in useEffect, the token gets created, as I can see it in the network tab on the Chrome debugger.  But, the response api call never gets made.  Do you know why this is?  Here is my code:

```
const [data, setData] = useState({
    message: '',
    error: null,
    loading: true
  });
  const [userData, setUserData] = useState(null);

 const serverUrl = 'http://localhost:5000';

const loginOrCreateUser = useCallback(async () => {
    try {
      const token = await getAccessTokenSilently();
      const response = await fetch(`${serverUrl}/users/login`, {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
        },
        method: "POST",
        body: {
            name: user.name,
            email: user.email,
            _id: user.sub
        }
      });

      const responseData = await response.json();

      setUserData(responseData);
      console.log(userData);
    } catch (error) {
      setData({...data, error: error.error});
    }
  });

  useEffect(()=> {
    loginOrCreateUser();
  }, []);

return (
    isAuthenticated && (
      <div>
        <img src={user.picture} alt={user.name} />
        <h2>{user.name}</h2>
        <Button onClick={callApi}>Call API</Button>
        <p>{JSON.stringify(data.message)}</p>
      </div>
    )
  );
}
```

Comment: Do you get any error in catch block? Try adding `console.log` there

Comment: I tried putting in a console.log under the token, but nothing showed up in the console.

Comment: Not under token, put `console.log(error)` after `} catch (error) {`

Comment: Ok, that was really helpful.  I'll do that from now on.  I think I have an idea of where to look now.

Comment: Also, try not to put a `console.log(myVariable)` directly after `setMyVariable()` - better to put the log into a `useEffect()` - that way it'll execute after `myVariable` has been updated.